# Report mis display on web application

Tags: java, jasper-reports, zk

I have a funny situation when generate report with *JasperReports*. I did some code and its generate report correctly. But when my friend connect to my pc and execute it, the report is showing in my pc and not my friend :).

Can someone tell me what is wrong? I'm using ZK CE for front end.

```
@Command
public void printPC() throws JRException, SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException
{
    String file1 = "/WEB-INF/pages/procurement/report/productCategoryReport.jrxml";
    InputStream Is = WebApps.getCurrent().getResourceAsStream(file1);

    JasperDesign jasperDesign =JRXmlLoader.load(Is);
    JasperReport jasperReport =JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null, getConnection());

    JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint,false);

    getConnection().close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use zk as frontend and you want to display something in zk,
you have to give zk the data, but you just call `Jasper` methods.

I don't know `Jasper`, but if it has got textoutput, it should look like

zul:

```
<textbox id="out">
<.... ="@command('printPC', out=out)" ...>
```

Java

```
public void printPC(@BindingParam("out")Textbox out) throws Exception {
   ...
   out.setValue(jasperTextOutput);
   ...
}
```

Or for html output use zks [`Html`](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zul/Html.html#setContent%28java.lang.String%29) component.